# dynamic import in webpack 2 not working

Tags: webpack-2

I want to use dynamic import in webpack 2. I use webpack 2.4.1

index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Root from './containers/Root'
import '../styles/custom.scss'

var btn = document.getElementsById('button');
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    import('./assets/chunk.css').then(()=>{
        console.log("Success")
    })
});

render(
  <Root />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

But when I run "npm start" it didn't work and notify an error at line 9 of index.js

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (9:4)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you install `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`?

Comment: Thanks for your support. Sorry for the delay. I tried to install but it still didn't work for me.

Comment: Oh, this is my fault. I forgot include plugin in webpack.config.js.
rules: [
   {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [['es2015', {modules: false}]],
            plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import']
          }
        }]
   }]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As wuxiandiejia mentioned, the answer is

1. install `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`
2. make sure `'syntax-dynamic-import'` appears in your babel `options.plugins`

Example `babel.rc`

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
}
```